# Disable a Dialog Button in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, button, dialog, ckeditor

I try to write a plugin for the CKEditor (Version 4.x), with a Dialog UI element.

the definition of the dialog looks like:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('abbrDialog', function(editor) {
return {
    title: editor.lang.abbr.title,
    label: editor.lang.abbr.title,
    minWidth: 400,
    minHeight: 200,

    contents: [{
            id: 'abbreviation-dialog',
            label: editor.lang.abbr.label,
            elements: [
              {
                id: 'abbreviation-found-label',
                type: 'html',
                label: editor.lang.abbr.found,
                html: '<span id="foundLabelId">'+ editor.lang.abbr.found + '<\/span>'
              },
              {
                id: 'abbreviation-current-item',
                type: 'html',
                label: editor.lang.abbr.currentLabel,
                html: '<span id="currentLabelId">'+ editor.lang.abbr.currentLabel + '<\/span>'
              },
              {
                id: 'abbreviation-replace-button',
                type: 'checkbox',
                label: editor.lang.abbr.replaceButton,
                onClick : function() {
                  replaceAbbreviation(editor.lang.abbr.currentLabel, editor.lang.abbr.noMore);
                }
              },
              {
                id: 'abbreviation-next-button',
                type: 'button',
                label: editor.lang.abbr.nextButton,
                onClick : function() {
                  nextAbbreviation(editor.lang.abbr.currentLabel, editor.lang.abbr.noMore);
                }
              },
              {
                id: 'abbreviation-all-button',
                type: 'button',
                label: editor.lang.abbr.allButton,
                onClick : function() {
                  replaceAllAbbreviations(editor.lang.abbr.currentLabel, editor.lang.abbr.noMore);
                  //alert('Replace all!!');
                }
              }]
        }],

    buttons: [CKEDITOR.dialog.okButton],

    onShow: function() {
      initDialog(editor.lang.abbr.found, editor.lang.abbr.currentLabel);
    },

    onOk: function() {
      // nothing to do
    }
```

In one function i try to disable a button. This looks like:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().getContentElement("abbreviation-dialog", "abbreviation-replace-button").disable();
```

Unfortunately this button gets not disable (but the additional CSS-class `cke_disabled` is added).

Also strange: if i turn that `abbreviation-replace-button` into a checkbox, this checkbox gets disabled (with no further code modifications).

My Questions:

- How can i disable a button on a plugin dialog?
- Why gets the checkbox disabled but the button not?
- Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call a special method to disable buttons,
i.e. `disableButton('btn')

you can disable `ok` or `cancel` button by following way

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().disableButton('ok')
CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().disableButton('cancel')
```

in your case you can try

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().disableButton('abbreviation-next-button')
```